# jqueryui selectmenu with vue v-model

Tags: vue.js, jquery-ui

I had a great working `<select>` with a `v-model` on it which worked just fine. Then I wanted to stick some extra elements inside the `<option>` tags and for that I had to use jqueryui and its `selectmenu` element. This seems to have destroyed my `v-model` and now that I have nice extra elements inside the new jqueryui options list, it no longer sets my model.

Well, I'm now just using the jqueryui selectmenu's change event to adjust the former model manually by simply setting the new value to the vue data variable. This works, but is there a better way one can still use the jqueryui stuff and still take advantage of vue's `v-model`?